# Changed form control padding of drop down list and drop down list doesn't display any options

Tags: css

I am building a web application using ASP.NET MVC. I have changed the padding on the form control class and the drop down list is not displaying any options.

The padding was originally set to:

```
.form-control {
    padding: 6px 15px;
}
```

with the above setting, I can see the option in the textbox

Now i wanted to make my textboxes and dropdown lists bigger. So I changed the padding to:

```
.form-control {
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

Now I cannot see any option in the dropdown list. As I increase the top-bottom padding from 6px to 20px, I can see that the option is slipping away from the view. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a bootstrap form-control has a fixed height of 34px.  Try setting the height to 'inherit' so it will cancel-out the 34px setting.

```css
.form-control {
    padding: 20px 15px;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It ended up making my textboxes and dropdown lists bigger but the selection option inside the dropdown list didn't appear